# python ubuntu virtualenv -> error

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

Newbie here, be kind.

The other day I am all:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

And then I am (following instructions):

```
virtualenv env
```

And Ubuntu 10.10 is like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2675, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.5.1
```

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `python-virtualenv` package should have installed `virtualenv` in `/usr/bin/`.

Instead, the traceback error message says you are running `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. Perhaps uninstall the `/usr/local` version of `virtualenv`, and try again.

Comment: Awesome, a certain amount of purging and reinstalling and deleting by hand lots of likely looking things in /usr/local and restarting of shells and everything looks nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: for me, it was just deleting /usr/local/bin/virtualenv

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04..

Turns out it was only because apt installed python-virtualenv 1.4, which was too old.

I removed the deb package and used `pip install` instead and it worked fine.

```
pip install virtualenv
```